# analysis of measurements over time

Tags: time-series

I have blood pressure measurements for a patient over 10 time points (not equally spaced). The patient was injected with a drug after the first time point and would like to answer the question whether the drug has an effect on the patient’s blood pressure over time.  Is there a statistic that can be used to answer this question? Can a simple t test be used?

Thanks

Comment: Where are we on this question? did you receive your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking in to the [paired t-test](http://www.biostathandbook.com/pairedttest.html) before and after the drug was taken.

If you have information about delayed effect of the drug, you could use it in the test.

If not, it could also be inferred using [MLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood).

Comment: Thanks Uri. Since the t test assumes the independent observations, can I still use the t test given that blood pressure measurements depend on time?

Comment: I would incorporate this dependency in to the model